# Failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:6600': Address already in use

Tags: ubuntu, mpi, mpd

I'm using ubuntu 12.10 for my MPI(message passing interface) configuration I have installed mpd after installation I have start mpd, it is started normally no error message display but when I'm trying to run the command "mpd &" it gives me error message "Failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:6600': Address already in use" I have tried many solutions but the result is same.

```
root@ub0:~# service mpd start

Starting Music Player Daemon mpd
[ OK ] root@ub0:~# service mpd restart

Stopping Music Player Daemon mpd
[ OK ] Starting Music Player Daemon mpd
[ OK ] root@ub0:~# mpd &

[1] 2881 root@ub0:~# Failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:6600': Address already in use

[1]+ Exit 1 mpd
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you're trying to run the daemon twice. It should be pretty obvious why this fails; the first time it ran, it bound that address, and running it again fails to bind to it because the first instance is already bound.

Comment: Assuming this is TCP, and you know the port number (e.g. your 6600), use `lsof -itcp:6600 -stcp:listen` to find out what's running already on that port. More generic: `lsof -i :6600` ...

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because it's already running:

```
[ OK ] Starting Music Player Daemon mpd
```

You don't need to start it by hand (by doing `mpd &`), your init system is taking care of that.

Comment: means it will work fine even i have'nt start it?

Comment: You have started it. You ran `service mpd start`

Comment: okay thnx may u live long...